# In Data Lake, can we output data to Azure Storage?

Tags: azure-data-lake

I found Data Lake Storage is slow and not stable using c# SDK, want to output data into Azure Storage using Output statement, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes one can write the output of their job to Azure Storage as long as the storage is part of the same subscription and is configured to access it.

You can use the following link which describes how to run jobs in Azure Data Lake Analytics and write the output in Azure Storage using the .NET SDK

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-manage-use-dotnet-sdk

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am hoping to output file to azure using Output statement directly.